# How to use the docker gitlab-runner to exec stages locally

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup a gitlab runner in docker on my local machine. It all is working fine. When the pipeline starts, the runner seems to handle the workload

But, I would like to do this locally. For example, if you downloaded the gitlab-runner executable, you can run stages locally

```
$> gitlab-runner exec docker  linting
```

But in my case I have the runner started in docker and I don't have the executable `gitlab-runner`. So my question is, is there a docker equivalent for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gitlab-runner exec` works as its own standalone command and runs the job in the context of where the executable is called -- it will not cause the job to be run on a registered runner. It is solely a local operation, so you must have the binary available.

You can run `gitlab-runner exec` inside of your runner container or a new container if you want.

For example (assuming Linux platform):

```
docker run --rm \
       -v $(pwd):/workspace \ # mount directory to the container
       --workdir /workspace \ # set working directory
       -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ # enable docker
       --privileged \
       --entrypoint="gitlab-runner" \ # set entrypoint
       gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest exec docker MY_JOB
```

Or use `doker exec` to run the command on your existing container:

```
docker exec -it my-running-container-name gitlab-runner exec docker linting
```

Though, you will want to make sure the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and project files are present in the container when you start it...

Comment: The command `gitlab-runner exec docker linting` is working on my Mac, but when I execute `docker exec -it 63c62b7c4850 "gitlab-runner exec docker linting"` I get the following error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "gitlab-runner exec  docker linting": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: I also tried `docker exec -it  63c62b7c4850 "/usr/bin/gitlab-runner exec  docker linting"` which gives a little bit different error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/bin/gitlab-runner exec  docker linting": stat /usr/bin/gitlab-runner exec  docker linting: no such file or directory: unknown` Both commands are executed in the root of my project which contains the yml. Any suggestions what the problem is?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri try removing the quotes. You'll also need to make sure the project files exist _inside_ the container.